# How to delay page rendering until data received from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

When the page load for the first time with API request it errors out. but after page load if I put the same code back it works fine. Can someone please help what am I  missing here. Or show me the trick to delay the page loading until data loads from API.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function ProductPage({ data }) {

const [productData, setProductData] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    getProductdata()
}, [])

async function getProductdata(){
    const secret = "SECRET"
    const request = await fetch(`https://app.myapi.com/api/products/${data.productsCsv.id}`, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(secret)}`,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then((request => request.json()))
      .then(data => setProductData(data))
      .catch(err=>console.log(err))  
    }
    
   console.log("pdata",productData) // returns null on initial load and then it filled with data.

   
return (
    <>
     <div className="stock mb-4 ">
                    <p className="tracking-wider mb-2">Size</p>
                        {productData.variants.map((variant,index)=>{
                            <p>{variant.stock}</p>
                            if(variant.stock != 0){
                            return (
                                
                                
                                    <button className={`p-2 border-gray-200 border mr-2 mb-2 hover:bg-black hover:text-white cursor-pointer focus:border-black ${activeSize === index ? 'bg-black text-white' : null}`} role="button" tabIndex={0} 
                                    onClick={() => {toggleSize(index); setSize(size)}}
                                    onKeyDown={() => {toggleSize(index); setSize(size)}} key={index}>{variant.variation[0].option}-{variant.stock}</button>
                            
                                    
                                )
                            }
                            else {
                                return(
                                    <button className={`p-2 border-gray-200 border mr-2 mb-2 ${variant.stock == 0 ?'bg-gray-400 line-through text-red-500': null}`} disabled role="button" tabIndex={0} 
                                    onClick={() => {toggleSize(index); setSize(size)}}
                                    onKeyDown={() => {toggleSize(index); setSize(size)}} key={index}>{variant.variation[0].option}-{variant.stock}</button>
                                )
                            }
                            })} 
                            
                </div>
</>
)
```

Comment: retry request by `      .catch(getProductdata) `

Comment: But your `productData` ***is*** initially `null` and will be on any subsequent renders until updated by the GET request. You are also console logging as an unintentional side-effect, so what you see actually logged shouldn't be a true measure of anything. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: so my code errored out at "productData.variants" loop saying Can not read property of null.

So if I remove the code from my return statement and refresh my page the error is gone and when I add same code in my return statement it works fine as productData is no more null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a bit of state and return another component until you have your data, it should look something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function ProductPage({ data }) {

const [productData, setProductData] = useState(null)
const [loading, setLoading] = useSate(true) // set some state for loading

useEffect(() => {
    getProductdata()
}, [])

async function getProductdata(){
  const secret = "SECRET"
  const request = await fetch(`https://app.myapi.com/api/products/${data.productsCsv.id}`, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(secret)}`,
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    }).then((request => request.json()))
      .then((data) => {
        setProductData(data)
        setLoading(false) // set Loading to false when you have the data
      })
      .catch(err=>console.log(err))  
}
    
//use the piece of loading state to return other component until you have the data
if (loading) { 
  return (<div>Replace me with a loading component...</div>)
}
  
return (
  <>
  ...
  </>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

Your `productData` ***is*** initially `null` and will be on any subsequent renders until updated by the GET request. Attempting to access the `productData.variants` throws the error because `productData` is null.

## Solution

You can use some loading state and conditionally render your UI. Use a null-check/optional chaining operator on the `productData` state.

```
const [productData, setProductData] = useState(null);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // <-- loading state

useEffect(() => {
  getProductdata();
}, []);

async function getProductdata() {
  setIsLoading(true); // <-- ensure loading true
  const secret = "SECRET";
  const request = await fetch(
    `https://app.myapi.com/api/products/${data.productsCsv.id}`,
    {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(secret)}`,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  ).then((request => request.json()))
    .then(data => setProductData(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .finally(() => setIsLoading(false); // <-- clear loading state success or fail
}

if (isLoading) return <div>Loading Data</div>; // <-- render loading UI

return (
  ...
  {productData?.variants?.map(......)}
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's null because it's initialized as null in your useState hook.
This is normal.

The useEffect hook should look like this.

```js
useEffect(() => {

    function getProductdata() {
        const secret = "SECRET"
        return fetch(`https://app.myapi.com/api/products/${data.productsCsv.id}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(secret)}`,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }

    getProductdata().then((request => request.json()))
      .then(data => setProductData(data))
      .catch(err=>console.log(err));

}, []);
```

You can prevent showing the data by using a logical AND && operator in the template to check if the variable is not null.

```js
{productData && productData.variants.map((variant,index)=> ...
```

I didn't test this code.

---

Side note:
That SECRET isn't secret. It will appear in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `productData.variants` doesn't exist so the map function returns an error.
Add a conditional statement that checks `productData` before the map function.

```
{productData ? (
    productData.variants.map((variant,index)=>{
        //rest of code
    }
) : null}
```

So if `productData` is `null` the map function does not execute. This is a [Ternary Operator](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/ternary-operator), very useful when writing ReactJS.

You can even add a `<p>Loading Data</p>` instead of just `null` so the user knows data is loading instead of a blank area:

```
{productData ? (
    productData.variants.map((variant,index)=>{
        //rest of code
    }
) : (
    <p>Loading Data...</p>
)}
```